# Chrome CSS Issue for classes

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to get some CSS to work for a website I am working on for someone. Works fine with no issue whatsover in IE and Firefox, but Chrome is being a pain.

This is the element I am working with at the moment, that I am having issues with:

```
<div class="bubble">
            <h2><a href="viewpost?id=<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['postTitle']; ?></a></h2>
            <p>
            Posted on <?php echo $row['postDate']; ?>
            <br />
            <?php echo $row['postDesc']; ?>
            </p>
            <p><a href="viewpost?id=<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>">Read More...</a></p>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS for this element:

```
.bubble
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    margin:0;
    color: #000;
    background: #0F9;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0f9), to(#0CC));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(#0f9, #0CC);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(#0f9, #0CC);
    background:linear-gradient(#0f9, #0CC);
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:25px 50px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:25px 50px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:25px 50px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:25px 50px;
    -moz-border-radius:25px / 50px;
    border-radius:25px / 50px;
}

.bubble:before
{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-30px;
    right:80px;
    border-width:0 0 30px 50px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:transparent #0CC;
    /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
    display:block;
    width:0;
}

.bubble:after
{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-30px;
    right:110px;
    border-width:0 0 30px 20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:transparent #fff;
    /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
    display:block;
    width:0;
}

.bubble a
{
    color: #03F;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.bubble a:hover
{
    color: #09C;
    text-shadow: #fff 0 0 10px;
    filter: glow(color=#fff, strength=5);
}
```

Like I said, works perfectly fine and looks great in Firefox or IE, but in chrome, it's not applied whatsoever.

It is to create chat bubbles for blog posts on the site.

In order to get it to work in Chrome, I have to go and clear out my entire cache for chrome (not just this specific site), and restart chrome to get it to take effect, if it even works to begin with.

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: a what? never heard of that before.

Comment: Nevermind, figured out what plunker was:

https://plnkr.co/edit/YMLi2Zgfz6AFIN47Rx0S